# Fill empty cell with what's on the next row

Tags: pandas

I've scraped a PDF table and it came with an annoying formatting feature.

The table has two columns. In some cases, one row stayed with what should be the column A value and the next stayed with what should be the column B value. Like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['names'] = ['John','Mary',np.nan,'George']
df['numbers'] = ['1',np.nan,'2','3']
```

I want to reformat that database so wherever there is an empty cell on df['numbers'] it fills it with the value of the next line. Then I apply .dropna() to eliminate the still-wrong cells.

I thied this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  if df['numbers'][i] == np.nan:
    df['numbers'][i] = df['numbers'][i+1]
```

No change on the dataframe, though. No error message, too.

What am I missing?

Comment: and what if `df['numbers'] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '3']`, what shoud be the result?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think this solves all your problems, the reason why you are not updating the dataframe is the line
`if df['numbers'][i] == np.nan:` , since this always evaluates to False.

To implement a vlaid test for nan in this case you must use
`if pd.isnull(df['numbres'][i]):` this will evaluate to True or False depending on the cell contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
df[['numbers']] = df[['numbers']].fillna(method='bfill')
df = df[~df['names'].isna()]
```

It's probably not the most elegant, but it worked.